# Catalog Price Rule Not Firing

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I have a new Magento 1.9 CE site and am attempting to create the first catalog price rule - a 25% discount for a specific customer group.  I have created the group, created and activated the rule, reindexed prices, added a customer to the group and displayed the product logged in as that customer - I see the standard price, not discounted price.

I have tried the rule two ways - the first is quite specific, explicitly setting an 'Any of These' condition declaring all the categories and subcategories, with dates spanning from 2000 to 2099.  The second is as general as possible:  no conditions, no dates, only the customer group and discount.  Neither version is applied.  I'm sure there must be some step I'm missing - a global setting perhaps? Any help you can give will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Total Noob mistake - 'Save and Apply' button.  Hope never to waste anyone's time like that again. J